# Export from tinymce to pdf/docx

Tags: php, pdf, tinymce, export, phpdocx

I use the tinyMCE editor, I save its data with mysql, in html from what I can see.

How can I export this data of my users to pdf and docx with php (serverside) ?

I believe the free edition of phpDocx lacks that functionality (embedHTML function missing)

Is there an alternative ?

Comment: +1 for sharing own solution way and confirming mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your html code to a html file serverside and use a library like [this one](http://www.fpdf.org/?lang=en) to create a pdf file.

Comment: Thank you. I've already implemented it using the Tcpdf library which can also write html to a pdf.